# Generate and combine type definitions in TypeScript monorepo

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, tsc

I have a monorepo with multiple packages depending on each other. Pack-A uses Pack-B. If I generate a d.ts file for Pack-A with tsc there are only classes from Pack-A. Classes from Pack-B are not defined but only imported. So if I add Pack-A to another project all classes from Pack-B are unknown. I would have to generate a separate Pack-B definition which I don't want. I want it combined in one single file. FYI: I use the definition for a node package which I then will reference as a tarball.